# how to check if sympy expression contains instance of Integral or NonElementaryIntegral?

Tags: sympy

How to check if an expression returned from sympy `integrate` command still contain an instance of integrals.Integral *or* ? `NonElementaryIntegral`

I am trying to check the antiderivative from sympy to see if it was successful or not, by checking if it remains unevaluated or not

For example:

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
isinstance(Integral(x**2, x),integrals.Integral)
```

Works and returns `True`. But if the expression has one instance `Integral` inside other expressions, how to check?

I need a way to look at the expression tree and see if at least one instance of `integrals.Integral` exist in it, and return True. I am not sure how to iterate over it and do this at this time.

I tried the following (I am very much a newbie in Python and sympy).

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
expr=integrate((-x**2+2)*exp(x/(x**2+2))/(x**3+2*x),x)
```

which gives

```
-Integral(-2*exp(x/(x**2 + 2))/(x**3 + 2*x), x) - 
   Integral(x**2*exp(x/(x**2 + 2))/(x**3 + 2*x), x)

expr.args #which is tuple

  (-Integral(-2*exp(x/(x**2 + 2))/(x**3 + 2*x), x), -
      Integral(x**2*exp(x/(x**2 + 2))/(x**3 + 2*x), x))

any(isinstance(m, integrals.Integral) for m in expr.args)
```

But this gave `False`, why?

I also tried

```
for m in expr.args:
    isinstance(m, integrals.Integral)
```

And this gaves

```
False
False
```

I was expecting both to be True.

How to check if an expression contains *at least* one instance of `integrals.Integral` any where in it?

**Update**
Ok, found something. The integrals above are actually `NonElementaryIntegral`
 and not `Integral`. Looking at the expression tree of expr

```
srepr(expr)

"Add(Mul(Integer(-1), NonElementaryIntegral(Mul(Integer(-1), Integer(2), 
Pow(Add(Pow(Symbol('x'), Integer(3)), Mul(Integer(2), Symbol('x'))), 
Integer(-1)), exp(Mul(Symbol('x'), Pow(Add(Pow(Symbol('x'), Integer(2)), 
Integer(2)), Integer(-1))))), Tuple(Symbol('x')))), Mul(Integer(-1), 
NonElementaryIntegral(Mul(Pow(Symbol('x'), Integer(2)), 
Pow(Add(Pow(Symbol('x'), Integer(3)), Mul(Integer(2), Symbol('x'))), 
Integer(-1)), exp(Mul(Symbol('x'), Pow(Add(Pow(Symbol('x'), Integer(2)), 
Integer(2)), Integer(-1))))), Tuple(Symbol('x')))))"
```

So I need to look for both `Integral` and `NonElementaryIntegral`. But so far, I do not know how to check for `NonElementaryIntegral` since I do not know in which class it is supposed to be. It is not  `integral.NonElementaryIntegral` and need to find where this lives.

```
any(isinstance(mx, integrals.NonElementaryIntegral) for mx in anti.args)
```

gives

```
 error: module 'sympy.integrals.integrals' has no attribute 
        'NonElementaryIntegral'
```

The page http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html only says

```
If the indefinite Integral returned by this function is an instance of 
NonElementaryIntegral, that means that the Risch algorithm has proven that 
integral to be non-elementary.
```

Ok, but how to check for it?

Comment: The example of `expr` that you gave was a bit misleading (at least it confused me) because when one executes the assignment `expr= Integral(-2*exp(x/(x**2 + 2))/(x**3 + 2*x), x) - Integral(x**2*exp(x/(x**2 + 2))/(x**3 + 2*x), x)` the result is not the same as you get from SymPy by trying to `integrate` those functions. SymPy prints `Integral` but the class name is actually different. Can't trust the print output.

Comment: @Alex I've put the actual integrate command in there. It takes little time to evaluate.  I first got confused by the display. sympy shows it as `Integral` on the screen, but it turned out to be `NonElementaryIntegral` and first I was checking just for `Integral`. I did not there is also another one !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr.has(Integral)
```

does this. The class NonElementaryIntegral [inherits from Integral](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/integrals/risch.py#L1562), so according to [inheritance rules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) it suffices to check for `Integral`.

A self-contained example would be

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
expr = integrate(exp(x**4)/(x**2+1), x)
print(expr.has(Integral))
```

You can find detailed information about the class names by using

```
print([type(a) for a in preorder_traversal(expr)])
```

Comment: Can you please explain why one needs `from sympy.integrals import risch` when the line above it is `from sympy import *`? Isn't the `import *` meant to import eveything from `sympy`? (I am just starting to learn python/sympy) but this is little confusing for me why both are needed.

Comment: Packages can decide what is imported when you do `import *`. [Docs on import *](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: Thanks. But I just found out that `any([isinstance(a, integrals.Integral) for a in preorder_traversal(expr)])` returns `True` also! But there is no instance of `integrals.Integral` in the expression? There is only 2 instance s of `risch.NonElementaryIntegral`. It looks like `integrals.Integral` is  superset  and constains  `risch.NonElementaryIntegral`? So I just really need to check for `integrals.Integral` and this will catch both cases? Does this sound ok?

Comment: Yes, this works because the class `NonElementaryIntegral` is derived from Integral. I revised the answer to explain this more. Also, I think you don't need to write `integrals.Integral`; simply `Integral` should be enough.

Comment: You can just use `expr.has(Integral)`. That will be equivalent to what you have here.